# how to use like clause in neo4jclient in windowform C#

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

i user neo4jclient for query data but i don't how to use like clause same SQL, right now it just use get specific

here is full code

```
                  var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"),   "username", "password");
                  client.Connect();
                  var apps = client.Cypher
                  .Match("(a:App)")
                  .Where("a.Name =~ {nameParam}")
                  .WithParam("nameParam", string.Format("'.*{0}.*'", nameapps))
                  .Return(a => a.As<APP>())
                  .Results;

                foreach (var application in apps)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("APPID:{0} - AppName:{1}", application.ID, application.Name);

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Where` becomes:

```
.Where("a.Name =~ {nameParam}")
.WithParam("nameParam", $".*{nameapps}.*")
```

You can also use `string.Format`:

```
.Where("a.Name =~ {nameParam}")
.WithParam("nameParam", string.Format(".*{0}.*", nameapps))
```

Check out the docs on Neo4j on [using Regex](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-where.html#query-where-regex) for more info.

Comment: when i replace at my code it show error at $".*{nameapps}".*)

Comment: It's a typo, the `"` is in the wrong place, additionally, it's using C#6, so you might need to use the `string.Format` version instead

Comment: i try to follow you code but it not work, sorry i'm newbie in neo4jclient T_T

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - what do you mean? Does it throw an exception? Do you have the DB running?